# How to implement indexOf method in single linked list?

Tags: java, list, data-structures

Below is my code in Java

```
public int indexOf(E item){
    Node<E> node =head;
    for(int i=0; i<size;i++) {
        node=node.next;
        if(node.data==item){
            return i+1;
        }
    }
    return -1; 
}
```

Is my code right or do I need to improve it?

Comment: It seems to me that you need to write some tests for this, to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my code right ...

That depends on your requirements.  If you are required to implement the `java.util.List` API, then the javadoc says this:

> *"... More formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index."*

You are using `==` instead of `equals` ... which is incorrect.

If you are not *required* to implement `List` then we cannot comment on the correctness of `==` ... or for that matter on any aspect of the code.  (For instance the requirements *could* say that list element positions start at 1!!)

> ... or do I need to improve it?

If it doesn't meet the requirements, you need to fix that.  (But we don't normally describe bug fixes as "improvements".)

If you are asking for a code review, such questions are better asked on the code-review site.

But stylistically, I wouldn't use a `for` loop.  I'd use a while loop, and use `node == null` as the loop termination condition.  (Your code has an implicit dependency on `size` being correct.  If it isn't you may get NPEs.)

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is not a primitive type, to ensure a thorough comparison you should use `node.data.equals(item)`.

Comment: If `node.data` is a primitive type then this will not work.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - if node.data is a primitive type then `Node<E>` is nonsense.  You can't use a primitive type as a generic type parameter.

Comment: True, however I was under the assumption that this data is not a primitive, since usually a `LinkedList` is used as a wrapper for non-primitives; otherwise, there'd be the prospect of using the default `LinkedList` with an autoboxed primitive.

Comment: @StephenC without seeing the definition of `Node` any answer to this question is a guess, but fair point.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - Granted.  But if the type of `node.data` is not `E` then the OP's design is nonsense ... and I think we should assume that it isn't nonsense, out of respect to him.